# How to get separate values from Xlement

Tags: c#, xml, linq

This is a portion of XML I'm trying to parse

```
<BRTHDATES>
  <BRTHDATE value="5/1/1963" code="B"/>
</BRTHDATES>

var birthdates = xmlDoc.XPathSelectElements("/INDV/PERSON/BRTHDATES").Elements().Where(e => e.Name == "BRTHDATE");

xe = birthdates.Elements().Where(e => e.Name == "BRTHDATE");
bbs = from b in birthdates
                      select new
                      {
                          Birthdays = b.FirstAttribute.Value,
                          Code = b?.Value
                      };

 var status = birthdates.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "BRTHDATE").Single().Value;
```

When I try to get "Value" from the Element I get an empty string.  I can't get anything for the "code" attribute.

It sure seems like this should be a lot easier...

Comment: Just a note.  As far as I know, there's nothing in the XML specs that dictates attribute order (there's a canonical/normative order (alphabetical by name)), but that's rarely used (and isn't used in your document)).  Picking out attributes by order will eventually bite you.  Have you considered using the elements `Attributes` collection?

Comment: you need Decendants instead of Elements.  You need an attribute "value"  :  var status = birthdates.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "BRTHDATE").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("value")).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code. I've already tested through a test project and got the require value.

```
           string personBirthday = string.Empty;

            string soapResult = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf - 8"" ?><INDV> <PERSON> <BRTHDATES><BRTHDATE value = ""5/1/1963"" code = ""B"" /> </BRTHDATES></PERSON></INDV> ";

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(new StringReader(soapResult));

            XmlNodeList person = doc.GetElementsByTagName("BRTHDATES");

            if (person[0].ChildNodes.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode item in person[0].ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (item.Name.Trim().Equals("BRTHDATE"))
                    {
                        personBirthday = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Attributes[0].Value) ? item.Attributes[0].Value.Trim() : string.Empty;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: That will work until the order of the attributes gets shuffled.  Remember, XML does not necessarily respect attribute order.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the solution

You can select specific Element from a Xml. Just try below sample code

```
XmlNodeList generalTabNodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/INDV/PERSON/BRTHDATES");

foreach (XmlNode node in generalTabNodeList)
            {
                if (node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    string birthdate = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.ChildNodes[0].ToString()) ? node.ChildNodes[2].InnerText.ToString() : string.Empty;
                }
            }
```

Comment: The OP want Linq and this is not linq.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite follow what you are trying to do, but, this should get you going:

For an XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<INDV>
  <PERSON>
    <BRTHDATES>
      <BRTHDATE value="5/1/1963" code="B"/>
    </BRTHDATES>
  </PERSON>
</INDV>
```

*(Note, this is an entire XML document - one that matches your code, not just the snippet you provided (that doesn't match your code))*

This code will pick out the `value` and `code` attributes:

```
 using (var xmlStream = new FileStream("Test.xml", FileMode.Open))
 {
     XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlStream);
     var birthDateElements = xmlDocument.XPathSelectElements("/INDV/PERSON/BRTHDATES/BRTHDATE");
     var birthDateElement = birthDateElements.FirstOrDefault();
     if (birthDateElement != null)
     {
         var attributes = birthDateElement.Attributes();
         var valueAttribute = attributes.Where(a => a.Name == "value");
         var codeAttribute = attributes.Where(a => a.Name == "code");
     }
 }
```

You can play around with this code to figure out what you want to do.  Whatever you do, don't pick out attributes by position, pick them out by name.

Comment: Op want linq and this is not linq.

Comment: @jdweng: I'm curious how you figured out that the OP "wants linq".  His question is "How to get separate values from Xlement".  Then he talks about "portion of XML I'm trying to parse".  Then he talks about "try to get 'Value' from the Element".  If I search this page for "linq", the first match is your comment.  My code uses XDocument (explicitly) and XElement/XAttribute (implicitly).  I also use LINQ's `Where` method.  I don't use the C# query syntax (as he does).  However, his "bbs" variable (which he gets from LINQ) isn't used afterwards, so I'm not sure why it's there.

Comment: Oh, and my code compiles and runs.  It's pretty much a minimal repro

Comment: The posting is tagged with Linq.